# Does RxJava Observable actually observe Retrofit so if I receive data then it will automatically make another exact same call?

Tags: android, rx-java

So I'm trying to make a messaging part working where a `Retrofit` API returns a list of messages for a conversation. Sure, the conversation refreshes each time the user chooses to refresh the Activity.

But say the recipient sends me a message, will RxJava Observable automatically make this exact same API call to Retrofit and retrieve the updated data?

If not then what's an easy way I can achieve that?

```
getApi().getConversationMessagesQuery(request)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((Response<GetConversationDetailsQuery> response) -> {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                List<Message> messages = response.body().getMessages();
                                RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = getAdapter();
                                if (adapter instanceof MessageListAdapter) {
                                    ((MessageListAdapter) adapter).setItems(messages, firstLoading);
                                } else {
                                    adapter = MessageListAdapter.getInstance(messages, firstLoading);
                                    setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                            }
                        }, (Throwable ex) -> {

                        }
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the RxJava Observable automatically makes this exact same API call to Retrofit and retrieves the updated data

No, RxJava cannot do that automatically for you.

> what's an easy way I can manage to do that?

With simple REST API calls there is no way to detect that the data has changed. You would have to implement some [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) based technology on your server to achieve this.